# Elasticsearch gives duplicate result

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have following search/cities index where element will have name and bunch of other properties. I perform following aggregate search:

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "multi_match" : {
        "query": "ana",
        "fields": [ "cityName" ],
        "type" : "phrase_prefix"
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "res": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "cityName"
        },
        "aggs":{
            "dedup_docs":{
                "top_hits":{
                    "size":1
                }
            }
        }            
    }
}
}
```

As result I get 3 buckets with keys "Anahiem", "ana" and "santa". Below is result:

```
"buckets": [
    {
      "key": "anaheim",
      "doc_count": 11,
      "dedup_docs": {
        "hits": {
          "total": 11,
          "max_score": 5.8941016,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "search",
              "_type": "City",
              "_id": "310",
              "_score": 5.8941016,
              "_source": {
                "id": 310,
                "country": "USA",
                "stateCode": "CA",
                "stateName": "California",
                "cityName": "Anaheim",
                "postalCode": "92806",
                "latitude": 33.822738,
                "longitude": -117.881633
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "ana",
      "doc_count": 4,
      "dedup_docs": {
        "hits": {
          "total": 4,
          "max_score": 2.933612,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "search",
              "_type": "City",
              "_id": "154",
              "_score": 2.933612,
              "_source": {
                "id": 154,
                "country": "USA",
                "stateCode": "CA",
                "stateName": "California",
                "cityName": "Santa Ana",
                "postalCode": "92706",
                "latitude": 33.767371,
                "longitude": -117.868255
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "santa",
      "doc_count": 4,
      "dedup_docs": {
        "hits": {
          "total": 4,
          "max_score": 2.933612,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "search",
              "_type": "City",
              "_id": "154",
              "_score": 2.933612,
              "_source": {
                "id": 154,
                "country": "USA",
                "stateCode": "CA",
                "stateName": "California",
                "cityName": "Santa Ana",
                "postalCode": "92706",
                "latitude": 33.767371,
                "longitude": -117.868255
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Question is why last bucket has key "santa" even tho I search for "ana" and why same city "Santa Ana" (with id=154) shows up in 2 different buckets (key "ana" and key "santa")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mainly because your `cityName` field is analyzed, and thus, when `Santa Ana` is indexed, the two tokens `santa` and `ana` are getting generated and used for bucketing.

If you want to prevent that you need to define your `cityName` field like this:

```
PUT search
{
    "mappings": {
        "City": {
            "properties": {
                "cityName": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You first need to wipe your index, recreate it with the above mapping and then re-index your data. Only then you'll get your bucket names as `Anaheim` and `Santa Ana`.

**UPDATE**

If you want `cityName` to be analyzed but also only get a single bucket in your aggregation, there is a way by defining a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html), where one part is analyzed and the other one is not, like this

```
PUT search
{
    "mappings": {
        "City": {
            "properties": {
                "cityName": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you let `cityName` be analyzed but now you also have `cityName.raw` which is not analyzed and that you can use in your aggregation like this:

```
    "terms": {
        "field": "cityName.raw"
    },
```

Comment: Val I actually want for cityName to be analyzed so "Sant Ana" would be returned if I search by "San" or "Ana". Is there way to eliminate duplicate entries? Basically the only reason I aggregate is to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: but wouldn't it mean that if I search for "ana" not "Santa ana" will not be returned since search is doing pefix for whole string?

Comment: You can still search for "ana" on the `cityName` field as you do now and you'll get the same results, but you'd aggregate on the `cityName.raw` field.

Comment: Thank you. I was mixing search and aggregation terms.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

The repeation is a behaviour of top_hits aggregation.

Check that nice tutorial:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/top-hits-aggregation

> When solely using the top_hits aggregation, it just repeats what is
>   already in the regular hits in the response.

Actually analyzing is nothing to do with it. So the below explenation is not true.

*In default settings Elasticsearch will split input to so called terms. Default analyzer will transform `Santa Ana` as 2 terms like [`santa`, `ana`]. End when searching for `ana` `Santa Ana` will also match.
You can read about how Elastichsearch work from here:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up*

Comment: Thank you @alpert. I would understand 'ana' triggering search but why 'santa' goes as key in bucket? Does it mean that if any term in that array hit both will be split into 2 buckets?

Comment: Actually that is the behaviour of top_hits aggregation. It repeats hits when its used alone. Check that nice tutorial: https://www.elastic.co/blog/top-hits-aggregation